# Angular: Dependency Injection with prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller, prototypal-inheritance

According to [Todd Motto's styleguide, Controllers chapter](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#controllers):

> **Inheritance**: Use prototypal inheritance when extending controller classes

I try to implement it in my controllers:

```
function BaseController(){
    'use strict';

    this._path = '';
    this._restService = undefined;
}

/**
 * Boring JSDocs
 */
BaseController.prototype.getById = function(id) {
    return this._restService.getById(this._path, id);
};

TagModalController.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);

/**
 * Even more boring JSDocs
 */
function TagModalController(CommunicationService, $modalInstance, mode, 
    id, CommandService) {
    'use strict';

    // boring assertions

    this.setPath('tags');
    this.setRestService(CommunicationService);
```

But, as you can see, I have to always set `restService` which is needed in `BaseController` for communication with server side. Is any possibility to inject it like `CommunicationService` is injected into `TagModalController`? Then my code will look like this:

```
function BaseController(CommunicationService){
    'use strict';

    this._path = '';
    this._restService = CommunicationService;
}
```

And method `this.setRestService(CommunicationService);` won't be needed anymore. Is there any way to achieve Angular DI with prototypal inheritance for controllers in AngularJS? Thank you in advance for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be considered a necessary evil. Even with ES2015 classes the arguments for parent class constructor [have to be specified explicitly with `super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super).

You may want to borrow the pattern that classes use for inheritance and do

```
angular.bind(this, BaseController)(CommunicationService, ...);
```

to pass variables to `BaseController` constructor, especially if there is more than one dependency that should be passed there.

BaseController isn't instantiated by `$controller` and thus doesn't benefit from Angular DI, `this` is the only thing that associates BaseController with children. In order to give it an access to TagModalController injected dependencies, they have to be assigned as `this` properties and thus exposed to scope (Angular controllers weren't designed with `this` in mind, and controllerAs is just syntactic sugar to remedy `$scope` drawbacks). Which is not a very good thing.