# Two AngularJS controllers with same logic

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have two divs, each requiring a controller to handle activities within it. Both controllers have different names of course.

This situation is problematic since it requires maintenance on two identical pieces of code.

I was considering two options and am seeking comments:

1. Deploy the **common** code into a separate file and, using jQuery, *include* the file into both controllers,
2. Create a new file with a function that would receive the same parameters as the controllers and that would contain the whole logic currently hosted within both controllers. Then, simply invoke this function from within both controllers.

In the second option, the body of the controllers would become a single statement, i.e. the invocation of the new function.

From posts I found, it looks that the first option does work. My question is (before I engage into significant changes and testing): Would the second option work as well? and if yes, is it better, equivalent or worse than the first?

### Edit

Though, as explained, the actual code is of no relevance to my question, I'm adding a set of sample pieces to illustrate my question, especially the second option.

So here is the initial arrangement:

**Controller 1**

```
myApp.controller("First_Controller", "$rootScope", "$scope" , [function($rootScope , $scope) {

   $scope.Do_Something = function () {
      // some code here
   }

}
```

**Controller 2**

```
myApp.controller("Second_Controller", "$rootScope", "$scope" , [function($rootScope , $scope) {

   $scope.Do_Something = function () {
      // some code here
   }

}
```

The idea is to convert this to:

**Controller 1 - NEW**

```
myApp.controller("First_Controller", "$rootScope", "$scope" , [function($rootScope , $scope) {

   Common_Function($rootScope , $scope) ;

}
```

**Controller 2 - NEW**

```
myApp.controller("Second_Controller", "$rootScope", "$scope" , [function($rootScope , $scope) {

   Common_Function($rootScope , $scope) ;

}
```

Where:

```
Common_Function = function ($rootScope , $scope) {

   $scope.Do_Something = function () {
      // some code here
   }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code? Without seeing exactly what you're doing it's difficult to comment, but in general, the Angular way to do these kinds of things is to put the common code into a service and inject the service into your controllers. You could also use ES6 classes and define a common controller class with the shared behavior and then subclass it.

Comment: Thank you @MikeFeltman. In fact, the details of the code are not important in this post. What I'm thinking about is the _concept_ of doing something that would behave like **include** without actually including anything. See? By passing the same parameters to the function as those of the controller (mainly `$scope`), whatever the code does when within a controller would be done much the same if it is contained within the invoked function. Well... this is what I'm thinking about, and the question is: Does it make sense?

Comment: Arguing with people about the code implies that you're not interested in the answer. If you ask a question and assume that somebody may know better than you about the subject, you have to trust their opinion (even if you don't trust, there are rules for the questions on SO). If there is code that can illustrate your case, please, post it and don't make the answerers beg for it. Describing code with words never works.

Comment: Dear @estus, first, I re-read my comment and couldn't find even a hint to an "argument". Second, the fact that I'm posting questions here should _inspire_ the assumption that I **do appreciate the fact that there are people around there that know better than me**. Third (and last), please check the edit I made and (at least I hope) you may find yourself agreeing with me about the irrelevance of the actual code.

Comment: If the two controllers contain identical code, why do you have two controllers, and not just one?

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. *The idea is to convert this to* - the point of code is to help readers get that idea properly. It is clear that this is a particular case of controller inheritance, and there are many ways to do this. You can search for 'angularjs controller inheritance'. It can be done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532584/3731501) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065881/3731501). Currently it looks best with ES6 classes and class inheritance (`this` is supposed to be used instead of $scope for class methods).

Comment: @JBNizet, I can think of a situation. See there are two controllers (corresonds to two states, say `create` and `edit`). Now having different controllers for both the states makes more sense; *but* say 70% of the code is exactly the same (fetching similar data, same data model, same button actions etc.) - how to prevent this duplication of code?

Comment: @JBNizet, the issue is (as suggested by Sahil) that two different divs can be loaded at the same time, both handling the same type of events. If I use the same controller for both, events will be fired on both and hence they need to display different names to suggest to the internal code when to do something and when to ignore the event.

Comment: @FDavidov no, not at all. Controllers are not singletons. Each div will have its own instance of the controller, having its own scope. Using two different controllers with the exact same code, or using a unique controller won't change anything.

Comment: @JBNizet, imagine DIV1 and DIV2 sharing the same controller. Then, add to the controller `$on....`. Both instances of the same controller will capture the event and, not knowing who they are representing (DIV1 or DIV2), they will both do something with the event while the desired behavior is that one of them would say **not for me**.

Comment: And how would that make a difference to have two *different* controllers with the exact same code inside, and thus both containing the same event handler? It would e so much easier to answer your question if you came up with a complete minimal example showing what you actually have and want to do.

Comment: @JBNizet, imagine that the 2 controllers are identical except for one single command/assignment, something like `var Who_am_I = "Controller_1"` (or `"Controller_2"`). See? The core of my question is abount having an almost empty controller whose functionality is defined within an external function, which is invoked within the controller.

Comment: Ah, so the controllers are not completely identical, as you said until now. Delegating to a single function is the solution you think is the best. A better solution, IMHO would be two controller classes inheriting a base class. Or a component with an attribute whoAmI.

Comment: @JBNizet, my apologies if my wording was somehow/sometimes misleading. I tried to provide (apparently not too good ) examples regarding the root question which you did address in your last post. Thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet: it looked like when this question was active, you had a good handle on the subject and a potential solution. Is there value in summarising the discussion above in an answer below, for completeness, and for the benefit of future readers?